# Record real time Audio from browser and stream to Amazon S3 for storage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, webrtc, amazon-kinesis, multipartfile

I want to record audio from my browser and live stream it for storage in Amazon S3. I cannot wait till the recording is finished as client can close the browser, so I would like to store what has been spoken (or nearest 5-10 second).

The issue is multipart upload does not support less than 5Mib chunks, and audio files will be for most part less than 5Mib.

Ideally I would like to send the chunks in 5 seconds, so what has been said in last 5 seconds to be uploaded.

Can it be support by S3? or should I use any other AWS service to first hold the recording parts - heard about kinesis stream but not sure if it can serve the purpose.

Comment: S3 can receive a file with up to 5MB every 5 seconds. You don't need to consider multi-part upload, it works fine for over 100MB files. Kinesis is limited to up to 1MB.

Comment: At the moment I am looking to stream audio to S3, so it will be appended to the existing recording unless person stop recording

Comment: DId you find a solution to this? I'm looking to do something similar, but it sounds like you cannot append to files in S3 so you cannot do the upload in chunks?